# Issue in sharing data between JavaScript and JSP files using window.open() function

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, jsp

In below example I am sharing data between JavaScript and JSP files. I can successfully send data from File1.js to File2.jsp, But I am not getting value back from File2.jsp to File1.js. It was working fine with IE5 when I used ShowModalDialogue function, but it is not working with window.open() function.

I tried using localStorage, but it is not working out. I am always getting returnValue, data1 and data2  as undefined or empty. Is there any solution to get value from the file2.jsp? Thank you in advance.

file1.js

```
function framedialog() {
    data1 = new Array();
    data2 = new Array();
    var pm = new Object();
    pm.data1 = data1;
    pm.data2 = data2;
    var url = "http://locahost:8080/File2.jsp";
    var returnValue = window.open(url, pm, '', '');
    if (returnValue == '1') {
        for (i in data1) {
            alert(data1[i]);
            alert(data2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

File2.jsp

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         var count=5;
         var tabco=new Array(count);
         function ActionOK(){
         tabco=['aa','bb','cc'];
         for(j in tabco){
         data1[j]=tabco[j];
         }
         tabcoTitle=['1','2','3'];
         for(k in tabcoTitle){
         data2[k]=tabcoTitle[k];
         }
         top.opener.returnValue="1";
         }
      </script>``
   </head>
   <body class="">
      <input type="button" name="ok" value="ok" onClick="ActionOk()">
   </body>
</html>

enter code here
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question but it looks like you are not trying to make two JavaScript files communicate with one another; a JSP file is not a JavaScript file (JSP stands for Java Server Pages)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Shashi! Please remember to format your code for readability. Instead of indenting you can use three backticks to mark the start of a code chunk. Otherwise, use a service like [this one](https://www.freeformatter.com/) to format it before sharing.

Comment: yes. I am trying to communicate between JS and JSP file.